# Running Python from a make with a specific enviroment

Tags: python, makefile, environment

I have a written a makefile to use to run Python code. The idea is it will allow me to run my linter, pytest, and run the code all in one command. Importantly, it will also spin up a python environment to use.

An excerpt of it looks like:

```
VENV := venv

all: venv

$(VENV)/bin/activate: requirements.txt
    python3 -m venv $(VENV)
    ./$(VENV)/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt

# venv is a shortcut target
venv: $(VENV)/bin/activate

run: venv
    flake8 --exclude=venv
    pytest --ignore=venv
    mypy advent_of_code/dayone.py
    python advent_of_code/dayone.py
```

The rest of the code is found here: https://github.com/andrewblance/advent_of_code_2020

However, when I run my code I do not think it is using this environment. I think it still uses my default python environment. When I run this code I can see the version of Pytest and mypy that is being used depends on what is installed on the default python environment.

Have I done something wrong that means when I run flake & etc that I don't use the new environment? How can I change it so it only uses the environment specified in the makefile, and how do I "turn off" the environment once I am done with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short: you can't.

Longer: every process has its own environment.  Its environment is inherited from the process that started it.  But, it's impossible for a child process to modify or change the environment of its parent.

Every command is a process.  So the `make` program is a process, and each command line that make invokes is a process.  So when you run the command `python3 -m venv $(VENV)` that starts a shell process, which runs `python3 -m venv ...` which is another process.  Then whatever change to the environment `python3` made is lost when `python3` exits, and whatever change to the environment was made in the shell that started `python3` is lost when the shell exits, and then other shells are started with other commands, and when all the commands are done `make` will exit and any changes made to its environment are lost when you get back to your shell prompt.

Comment: very informative. I understand now. 
so if I want to keep this setup, I would need to do something like ```./$(VENV)/bin/python3``` with every command

Comment: I don't think so but I'm not an expert in how venv works.  My understanding is that if you want it to be in effect you have to _source_ the output of activate into your current shell.  Running a `python` command has the same issue I showed above, it sets the environment in the python process, then that exits and puts you back in the shell and the environment is lost.  You have to _source_ the output of the `activate` command in each shell to have it take effect there.

Comment: ok, this seems like it will be a difficult thing to solve. So a line like ```./$(VENV)/bin/python3 -m pytest --ignore=venv``` would run a version of python from ```./$(VENV)/bin/``` but I wouldn't have sourced it, so the environment might not be set correctly?

Comment: Maybe, as I say I'm no expert at venv.  Is it enough to just run the python3 command from inside the venv?  I sort of thought you had to source the activate script to enable the venv before running commands.  But maybe that's not necessary.

Comment: One thing you can do is invoke a recursive make instance where the recursive instance is inside the venv.  Then everything that make does, and all its child processes do, will be in the context of that venv.